# Unhandled Runtime Error | TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, localhost, typeerror

[Error image on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxMc1.png)
Using Next.js 13
I am getting this error on google chrome, how do I fix it (or maybe just ignore it).
I am not using Codemirror and don't wanna use it anyways.

I have tried:

- Deleting ".next","node_modules","package-lock.json"
- npm cache clear --force
- npm install; npm run dev

```
$npm list 
├── @types/node@18.11.9
├── @types/react-dom@18.0.9
├── @types/react@18.0.25
├── autoprefixer@10.4.13
├── eslint-config-next@13.0.3
├── eslint@8.27.0
├── framer-motion@7.6.7
├── next@13.0.3
├── postcss@8.4.19
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-simple-typewriter@4.0.5
├── react-social-icons@5.15.0
├── react@18.2.0
├── tailwindcss@3.2.4
└── typescript@4.9.3
```

Terminal:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1259 ms (154 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 53 ms (130 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 102 ms (183 modules)
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 102 ms (184 modules)
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#how-it-works
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:262:55)
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#how-it-works
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:262:55)
```

Answer (score 4):

Disable the chrome extension named Blackbox it's working

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the following :
const hasUpdates = Boolean(updatedModules.length);
just needs to be:
const hasUpdates = Boolean(updatedModules && updatedModules.length);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this chrome extension : Blackbox - Select. Copy. Paste & Search ,
You have to disable it.